# Describing the language generated by this grammar

Tags: regular-language, finite-automata

I'm working on this discrete math problem

> Describe the language generated by the grammar $G = \{\Sigma, \Delta, S, \Pi \}$, where $\Sigma = \{0, 1 \}$, $\Delta = \{S, X, Y, Z \}$ and $\Pi = \{S \rightarrow 0X | 1Y, X \rightarrow 1Y |1Z, Y \rightarrow 0X | 0Z, Z \rightarrow 0|e \}$.

From my understanding, the language generated should be something like this

$$L = \{ 01110111 \}$$

there is no "loop" where a number goes back to the variable. I'm confused on how to solve this, I need enlightenment. Any help would be great.

Comment: Do some cases, what do you mean by $L=\{01110111\}$. Do you see that in the word you are going to produce you can not have $11$ as substring? Can you have $00$?

Comment: The word can either start with 0 or 1 and must be followed by a 1 which should be followed by a 0 and end with a 0. That's what I think. L is just the longest word that could be accepted @Phicar

Comment: Amm i really do not know what you mean by the longest word accepted, either way what i was asking you is well written in Brian's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For convenience I repeat the list of productions:

$$\begin{align*}
S&\to 0X\mid 1Y\\
X&\to 1Y\mid 1Z\\
Y&\to 0X\mid 0Z\\
Z&\to 0\mid\epsilon
\end{align*}$$

Notice that every $X$ production adds a $1$ to the string, and every $Y$ production adds a $0$.

Suppose that you begin a derivation by applying $S\to 0X$. Then you can alternately apply $X\to 1Y$ and $Y\to 0X$ as often as you like, but eventually you must apply either $X\to 1Z$ or $Y\to 0Z$, depending on which non-terminal symbol you have at that point. At this point you will have a string that begins with $01$, then alternates $0$s and $1$s, and ends in $Z$. Finally, the $Z$ either disappears or is replaced by $0$.

If you begin by applying $S\to 1Y$, you get a string that begins with $10$, then alternates $1$s and $0$s, and ends in $Z$, and again the $Z$ either disappears or is replaced by $0$.

Thus, at the stage when the string ends in $Z$, the rest of it can be any alternating string of $0$s and $1$s of length at least $2$. Thus, if $L_0$ is the set of strings of alternating $0$s and $1$s of length at least $2$, your language is

$$L=L_0\cup\{x0:x\in L_0\}\;.$$

The shortest strings in $L$ are those produced by the derivations

$$S\Rightarrow 0X\Rightarrow 01Z\Rightarrow 01$$

and

$$S\Rightarrow 1Y\Rightarrow 10Z\Rightarrow 10\;.$$

The shortest non-alternating string is the one produced by the derivation

$$S\Rightarrow 1Y\Rightarrow 10Z\Rightarrow 100\;.$$

The shortest string that has two distinct derivations is $010$, which is derived both by

$$S\Rightarrow 0X\Rightarrow 01Z\Rightarrow 010$$

and by

$$S\Rightarrow 0X\Rightarrow 01Y\Rightarrow 010Z\Rightarrow 010\;.$$

Comment: Ohh, I'm starting to understand it now. Can you explain the difference between `finding the language accepted by an automation` vs `finding a regular expression that defines the same language`?

Comment: @Calypso: There are various ways to describe a language. One is to characterize the words in the language in some way; I did this by identifying them as the words consisting either of at least two alternating zeroes and ones, or such a word followed by a single zero. Another is to give a regular expression that defines the language. Such a regular expression can be considered a description of the language, but it’s not the only possible way of describing the language.

Comment: If I try entering a string 0101 into this machine, it ends with 0101z where z can "disappear" Is this valid too?

Comment: @Calypso: Yes, that’s fine; that’s a string of alternating zeroes and ones, and it’s of length $\ge 2$.